# Alternative to select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in disbelief that I wasn't able to find this somewhere but I've been looking for a while and can't find anything, so I figured it would be worth asking here. What I need:

- The functionality of a `<select>` menu
- "options" that I can put elements in
- Not Twitter Bootstrap

That's all. I have a list of saved items that you can select from, but I also want to add a little 'x' icon or whatever in the option to delete it.

I figured someone would have already made this from a `<ul>` or whatever, but if it's out there I couldn't find it. The only working example of this I found needed Bootstrap, which I don't want to use. I can write this myself, but it would be hacky and I'm hoping it already exists and I can save myself the trouble. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a form containing checkboxes to allow the selection an deselection of the options?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ufcbecbu/

Comment: @pizza It needs to be a drop-down. It's a search page, and the options are saved criteria. I just want the ability to click something next to the option and I'll use that even to delete it.

Comment: @RobertRozas that's actually very close. Do you know what would be a non-hacky way to close it on any click, similar to a select menu?

Comment: Hello @user3779812 ...could you be more specific in order to modify the fiddle pls.

Comment: @RobertRozas If you click a <select> menu, then click anywhere, it will close. In the fiddle, you have to click the ul to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to tweak the selectmenu from jqueryui. http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

I got it started, check out the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/htqdmdtd/3/

**CODE**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label } );

        if ( item.disabled ) {
          li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
        }

        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( li );

        return li.appendTo( ul );
      }
    });

    $( "#filesA" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons" );

    $( "#filesB" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons customicons" );

    $( "#people" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
  });
  </script>
  <style>
    h2 {
      margin: 30px 0 0 0
    }
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
    }
    select {
      width: 200px;
    }

    /* select with custom icons */
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      top: 0.1em;
    }
    .ui-icon.video {
      background: url("images/24-video-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.podcast {
      background: url("images/24-podcast-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.rss {
      background: url("images/24-rss-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }

    /* select with CSS avatar icons */
    option.avatar {
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .avatar .ui-icon {
      background-position: left top;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<form action="#">

  <h2>Selectmenu with custom avatar 16x16 images as CSS background</h2>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="people">Select a Person:</label>
    <select name="people" id="people">
      <option value="1" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://retsmgr.discovermls.com/images/delete-16x16.gif&apos;);">John Resig</option>
      <option value="2" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://retsmgr.discovermls.com/images/delete-16x16.gif&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
      <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://retsmgr.discovermls.com/images/delete-16x16.gif&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#people-menu').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).is('span.avatar')) {
        $(event.target).parent('li').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: That's good visually, but do you know if there's any way to have an event triggered when I click the 'x'? As far as I know you can't do this with <select>, but I'm pretty new to this so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The #people-menu click event is fired when you click the x. Inside I check to make sure that the x was clicked (span.avatar) and not just selecting the name. see JS above.

Comment: Hey I have one more question. If I dynamically add an option to the select menu, how can I refresh the menu to have the new option?

Comment: Just call `$( "#people" ).iconselectmenu("refresh");` to update the selectmenu when you add a new option.

http://jsfiddle.net/htqdmdtd/4/
http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thought I tried that but I think I had the wrong selector.